# Powershell date count wrong

Tags: powershell, active-directory

i have a below code that check Date in Description and compare it with (Get-date).AddDays(-30) as below:

[image]

```
$DateMaxTime = (Get-date).AddDays(-30)
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase "OU=Users,DC=love,DC=potatoes,DC=loc"|select samaccountname, Description
$groups = '#Group1'
ForEach($group in $groups){
$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty samaccountname
Foreach ($user in $users){
$DataPart = $null
$UserdistinguishedName = $null
$DataPart=$user.description
$DatePart= $DataPart.substring(5,10)
$FinalDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($DatePart,'dd/MM/yyyy',$null)
    If ($FinalDate -lt $DateMaxTime  ){
    $AcountName = $user.samaccountname
    Write-Host "$AcountName ouf of scope"}

    else {Write-Host "$AcountName in scope"
        If ($members -notcontains $AcountName ) {
        Write-Host "$AcountName  not exists in the group $group"
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "#Group1" -Members $AcountName 
        $FinalResult += New-Object psobject -Property @{User=$AcountName}
         } 
        Else {Write-Host "$AcountName   exists in the group $group"}
    }
}}
```

When I execute the code the desired output is to check user that have date in description no older then 30 days and then I want to add group to them. But sth is wrong and it counts date incorrectly.

Then it says that user in in scopre of 30 days and then that is not as below:
[image]

And as i you can see user date is older then 30 days
[image]

I am not sure why, becasue if i change user OU to other location the script counts it correctly as below:

[image]

It means to me that probably that part of code do sth bad

```
$DatePart= $DataPart.substring(5,10)
    $FinalDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($DatePart,'dd/MM/yyyy',$null)
        If ($FinalDate -lt $DateMaxTime  )
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Perhaps you should't rely on the fixed position of the date part in the description. Try `$DatePart = $user.Description -replace '^(?:\D*(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}).*)', '$1'`

Comment: the same outcome:(

Comment: Then I suggest you add a `Write-Host $user.description` in the code to see what is actually in the description. Perhaps in that other OU, dates are written differently tou what you think?

Comment: Move `$AcountName = $user.samaccountname` to be _above_ the `if()` statement - otherwise it'll only ever update when a new user is out of scope - which is why you see the `simcod` username listed for subsequent "in-scope" users as well

Comment: Seems this is IT ! ty